# Opengl: earth texturing

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

i'm trying to use a texture to draw the Earth over a sphere. My sphere is composed by by quads, each quad is composed by two triangles:

```
void Sphere(float radius, int n_lat, int n_lon)
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); 
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    TextureManager::Inst()->BindTexture(1);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
for (float i = 0; i < n_lat; i += 1.f)
    for (float j = 0; j < n_lon; j += 1.f)
    {
        Vector3 p;
        GLfloat u;
        GLfloat v;
        // -- first triangle
        p = SphereCoord(i, j, n_lat, n_lon);
                glNormal3(p);

        u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
        v=0.5-asinf(p.z)/PI;
        glTexCoord2f(u,v);

        glVertex3(p * radius);

        p = SphereCoord(i + 1, j, n_lat, n_lon);
        glNormal3(p);

        u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
        v=0.5-asinf(p.z)/PI;
        glTexCoord2f(u,v);

        glVertex3(p * radius);


        p = SphereCoord(i + 1, j + 1, n_lat, n_lon);
        glNormal3(p);

        u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
        v=0.5-asinf(p.z)/PI;
        glTexCoord2f(u,v);

        glVertex3(p * radius);



        // -- second triangle
        p = SphereCoord(i, j, n_lat, n_lon);
                glNormal3(p);

        u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
        v=0.5-asinf(p.z)/PI;
        glTexCoord2f(u,v);

        glVertex3(p * radius);



        p = SphereCoord(i + 1, j + 1, n_lat, n_lon);
        glNormal3(p);

        u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
        v=0.5-asinf(p.z)/PI;
        glTexCoord2f(u,v);

        glVertex3(p * radius);



        p = SphereCoord(i, j + 1, n_lat, n_lon);
        glNormal3(p);

        u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
        v=0.5-asinf(p.z)/PI;
        glTexCoord2f(u,v);

        glVertex3(p * radius);
}
glEnd();
}
```

With this code don't obtain a correct texture mapping. Does anyone can give me some tips?

It looks like the texture is in someway repeated on the longitude axis:
[image: Image of the earth]

Comment: You should stop using the fixed-function pipeline functions, and use more modern and non-deprecated functions.

Comment: @user1071138 [Let me Google that for you](http://bit.ly/17DwR2e)

Comment: My issue is not the sphere, is the texture...it looks like it's repeated on the longitude axis

Comment: @Vallentin I disagree. Fixed-function is great to start learning GL, and saying otherwise does nothing to help solve the problem.

Comment: @jozxyqk I can agree with that, though that wasn't the point of my comment.

Comment: It looks like your code (after fixing as Xonar explained below) is calculating spherical coordinates, so if you find it still looks slightly distorted after those changes make sure your texture is using a Mercator projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your the calculation of your u:

```
u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/2*PI+0.5;
```

You are diving it by 2 then multiplying the result by PI. You should be diving by 2 and PI

```
u=atan2f(p.y,p.x)/(2*PI)+0.5;
```